# How to make my calculator print numbers instead of getting a parsing error?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been wanting to make a custom calculator for finding odds in a game but I'm running into a problem with having the denominator printing

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Roaming Odds</title>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var CharmMultiplier=1
        var BoostMultiplier=1
        function Multiply()
        {
            var Charm, Boost, RoamingAmount, Denominator, RoamingCalc, CharmMultiplier, BoostMultiplier;
            // checking to see if the user has charm or boost
            // having the charm halves the chance of finding a roaming (1/1024 becomes 1/512)
            
            switch(Charm) {
             case true:
                CharmMultiplier = 0.5
                break;
             case false:
                CharmMultiplier = 1
                break;
            default:
                CharmMultiplier = 1
            }  

            // having the boost decreases the chance by 4 (1/1024 becomes 1/256)
            // having both the boost and chance is supposed to make the odds go from 1/1024 to 1/128 (decreased by 8x)
            switch(Boost) {
             case true:
                BoostMultiplier = 0.25
                break;
             case false:
                BoostMultiplier = 1
                break;
            default:
                BoostMultiplier = 1
            }

            Result = 1024*CharmMultiplier*BoostMultiplier/RoamingAmount;
            document.RoamingCalc.Denominator.value=Result;

            

        }
    </script>
    <form name="RoamingCalc">
        <!-- all the factors to account for when calculating odds-->
        <label for="RoamingName">Roaming (optional):</label>
        <input type="text" id="RoamingName" name="RoamingName">

        <label for="Charm">Charm</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Charm">
        
        <label for="Boost">Boost</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Boost">

        <label for="RoamingAmount">Amount of Roamings Unlocked: </label>
        <input type="number" id="RoamingAmount" name="RoamingAmount">

        <label for="Denominator">Result: 1 in </label>
        <input type="number" id="Denominator" name="Denominator"><br>

        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="Multiply()">


    </form>
    

</body>
</html>
```

`

The error I keep on getting is: The specified value "NaN" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.
Multiply @ RoamingOdds.html:43
onclick @ RoamingOdds.html:66

I've tried rewriting line 43 since thats what keeps on highlighting but Im new to Javascript so Im probably doing a terrible job at it

Edit 3/12: code now works with help from you guys + changes

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Roaming Odds</title>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var CharmMultiplier=1
        var BoostMultiplier=1
        function Multiply()
        {
            var Charm, Boost, RoamingAmount, Denominator, RoamingCalc, CharmMultiplier, BoostMultiplier;
            
            // checking to see if the user has charm or boost
            // having the charm halves the chance of finding a roaming (1/1024 becomes 1/512)
            
            if (document.getElementById("CharmID").checked){
                CharmMultiplier = 0.5 ;
            }else{
                CharmMultiplier = 1 ;
            }

            // having the boost decreases the chance by 4 (1/1024 becomes 1/256)
            // having both the boost and chance is supposed to make the odds go from 1/1024 to 1/128 (decreased by 8x)

            if (document.getElementById("BoostID").checked){
                BoostMultiplier = 0.25 ;
            }else{
                BoostMultiplier = 1 ;
            }
            
            if (document.getElementById("RoamingNameID"))

            RoamingAmount = Number(document.getElementById("RoamingAmountID").value) || 1;

            Result = 1024*BoostMultiplier*CharmMultiplier*RoamingAmount
         
            document.RoamingCalc.Denominator.value=Result;

            

        }
    </script>
    <form name="RoamingCalc">
        <!-- all the factors to account for when calculating odds-->
        <label for="RoamingNameID">Roaming (optional):</label>
        <input type="text" id="RoamingNameID" name="RoamingName">

        <label for="CharmID">Charm</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="CharmID" name="Charm">
        
        <label for="BoostID">Boost</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="BoostID" name="Boost">

        <label for="RoamingAmountID">Amount of Roamings Unlocked: </label>
        <input type="number" id="RoamingAmountID" name="RoamingAmount">

        <label for="DenominatorID">Result: 1 in </label>
        <input type="number" id="DenominatorID" name="Denominator"><br>

        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="Multiply()">


    </form>
    

</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's correct but the problem is that `RoamingAmount` is `undefined`.
You should give it a value. `NaN` is the result of a number through `undefined`. Like follows:

```js
console.log(1/undefined);
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it showed how to remedy the problem (e.g., by retrieving the value of the input with the id `RoamingAmount`).

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the information from the input.
In your case:

```
RoamingAmount = Number(document.getElementById('RoamingName').value) || 1;
```

You use `document.getElementById('#id')` to select the element. After that, `.value` to get the value inside the input as text, and finally wrap everything in `Number()` to make it a number and being able to calculate.
As you are using for a division, using the ternary `|| 1` will make the number `1` for not affecting the result with an invalid or empty value

Result:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Roaming Odds</title>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var CharmMultiplier=1
        var BoostMultiplier=1
        function Multiply()
        {
            var Charm, Boost, RoamingAmount, Denominator, RoamingCalc, CharmMultiplier, BoostMultiplier;
            // checking to see if the user has charm or boost
            // having the charm halves the chance of finding a roaming (1/1024 becomes 1/512)
            
            switch(Charm) {
             case true:
                CharmMultiplier = 0.5
                break;
             case false:
                CharmMultiplier = 1
                break;
            default:
                CharmMultiplier = 1
            }  

            // having the boost decreases the chance by 4 (1/1024 becomes 1/256)
            // having both the boost and chance is supposed to make the odds go from 1/1024 to 1/128 (decreased by 8x)
            switch(Boost) {
             case true:
                BoostMultiplier = 0.25
                break;
             case false:
                BoostMultiplier = 1
                break;
            default:
                BoostMultiplier = 1
            }
            
            RoamingAmount = Number(document.getElementById('RoamingName').value) || 1;

            Result = 1024*CharmMultiplier*BoostMultiplier/RoamingAmount;
         
            document.RoamingCalc.Denominator.value=Result;

            

        }
    </script>
    <form name="RoamingCalc">
        <!-- all the factors to account for when calculating odds-->
        <label for="RoamingName">Roaming (optional):</label>
        <input type="text" id="RoamingName" name="RoamingName">

        <label for="Charm">Charm</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Charm">
        
        <label for="Boost">Boost</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Boost">

        <label for="RoamingAmount">Amount of Roamings Unlocked: </label>
        <input type="number" id="RoamingAmount" name="RoamingAmount">

        <label for="Denominator">Result: 1 in </label>
        <input type="number" id="Denominator" name="Denominator"><br>

        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="Multiply()">


    </form>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but I'm running into some trouble where the output is always 1024 (or 1 when its the result includes only variables).

Comment: Yes, that's true. There are other issues other than the parsing error. You are not getting the values from the inputs so that has to be added